# Datagridview export to Excel using XML format

Tags: c#

I tried Excel 12.0 object library to export datagridview to excel.  I don't want open the Excel instead I want to save  the file.I don't have Excel installed where I am going to run this application.  Is there anyway I can use XML format and save as Excel file? I saw the example using Dataset to XML. But I would like to export the data directly from Datagridview. Please let me know.

Thanks for any ideas..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [Excel XML Writer](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/) library?

Comment: That works a treat, but in general terms has been superceeded by the .xslx format.